# Suppose that $f = ι_{\mathbb{R}_+}$. Show that

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Suppose that $f = ι_{\mathbb{R}_+}$. Show that $0$ is in the boundary of dom f and that $∂f(0)$ is nonempty using the definition of the sub differential.

Any hints or suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify on what $f = ι_{\mathbb{R}_+}$ means? I have not seen this symbol before

Comment: This is pretty standard notation. $\mathbb{R}_+ := \{z \in \mathbb{R}\text{ s.t } z \ge 0\}$ and $i_{\mathbb{R}_+}$ is its indicator function.

Comment: @dohmatob More usual are the notations $\mathbf 1_A$ or $\chi_A$, with $A=\mathbb R_+$.

Comment: @OP Suggestion: Read the definition of the subdifferential then explain the **specific** problem you have to apply it here.

Comment: @Did: Nope you're --perhaps-- confusing indicator / indicator function in measure theory with indicator function in convex analysis. This is pretty standard notation, once more.

Comment: @dohmatob You might want to slowdown on the epithetes, I am confusing nothing, standard or not (enthusiasm is allright, but not if it leads to insult people).

Comment: @Did: Sorry if this came across as an insult. But I maintain this is **standard** notation in the given context (convex analysis).

Comment: I'm with @dohmatob on the notational issue. I've personally not seen dotless-i used in this manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By $\text{dom }f$, I suppose you mean the set on which $f$ is strictly less than $\infty$. Well, clearly in your case $\text{dom }f = \mathbb{R}_+$, and its boundary is $\{0\}$, which of course contains $0$. Finally, using the definition of subdifferentials, one computes
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{split}
\partial f(0) &:= \{v \in \mathbb{R} \text{ s.t }f(z) \ge f(x) + \langle v, z - 0\rangle\text{ }\forall z \in \mathbb{R}\} = \{v \in \mathbb{R} \text{ s.t }vz \le 0\text{ }\forall z \in \mathbb{R}_+\}\\
&= \{v \in \mathbb{R} : v \le 0\} \ne \emptyset.
\end{split}
\end{eqnarray}

Alternatively, you can use the theory of *proximal operators* to get
\begin{equation}
v = v - 0 \in \partial f(0) \iff 0 = \mathrm{prox}_f(v) = \mathrm{proj}_{\mathbb{R}_+}(v) = (v)_+ \iff v \le 0.
\end{equation}

Comment: Note that $f(z) = +\infty$ in case $z < 0$. Hence, the inequality in the definition of the subdifferential trivially holds for such $z$. I have corrected your answer.

Comment: Ya, you're definitely right. Pre-coffee posts...

Comment: @dohmatob, What would be the Prox Operator for $ f \left( x \right) = {x}_{+} $ (Projection on $ {\mathbb{R}}_{+} $)?